# Explain why there's no solution to the equation $2x-2x^2 = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, graphing-functions

How can you tell there's no solution to the equation $2x - 2x^2 = 1$.

The supporting information goes like this:

The diagram above shows the graph of $y = 7 + 2x - 2x^2$.

I tried to do this:
$2 \cdot 1^2 = 2y$.
therefore $y = 2-2 = 0$;

Comment: What kinds of solutions are you allowing? If you allow complex solutions you will of course have solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The equation has no real solution because $2x - 2x^2 - 1 = -(x-1)^2-x^2 < 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively (to lhf's more straightforward solution), you could just immediately check that the discriminant $b^2−4ac=4−8=−4<0.$ The discriminant is the term under the square root occuring in the quadratic formula. Since it is negative, the only solutions will be complex.

Comment: This is also a great answer. It's a tough choice between your answer and lhf's.

Answer (score 4):

We want to solve $2x^2-2x+1=0$, presumably in the reals. Look at the upward-facing parabola $y=2x^2-2x+1$.

Complete the square. We have $x^2-x=(x-1/2)^2-1/4$. Thus our equation can be written as 
$$y=2(x-1/2)^2+1/2.$$
The vertex of the parabola is at $x=1/2$. There, $y=1/2$, so the parabola is always above the $x$-axis. Thus it has no point in common with the $x$-axis, and therefore our equation has no real solutions.

The arithmetic is a little easier if we look at the equivalent equation $4x^2-4x+2=0$, which can be rewritten as $(2x-1)^2+1=0$. But $(2x-1)^2$ is always $\ge 0$ if $x$ is real. So we can't have $(2x-1)^2+1=0$ for real $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Another point of view:
If you are looking at
$2x^2-2x=-1$ in the integers,
the left side is even
and the right side is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\frac12+t$. Then $t^2=-\frac14$. So, $t$ and $x$ are not real.